program into Remix to run a BOT added money to contract address but cannot withdraw? how do i get back out can see the funds in Etherscan please help!
Hi Stupidly run a program that was given from a You Tube guy in Remix, it runs a BOT and front runs to get profits, it was adding profits when checking on the contract in Etherscan. So was thinking it was all good.
But the problems are I cannot withdraw from it!.
I can see the balance of the contract in Etherscan and it increases but i cannot withdraw.
Is this possible to withdraw from the contract and it is connected to my wallet.
Apologies for lack of understanding any help would be appreciated.

Generally attempting to withdraw from these scams just sends the ETH to the scammer... so just do nothing, it's lost.
